# Force element to wrap depending on sibling width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

As you'll see in the snippet and picture below, I have a container (grey) that contains a main element (green) and a footer.

The footer itself contains two elements (blue and yellow).

**What I want is that the footer second element (yellow) wraps if the footer (blue + yellow) is wider than the main element (green).**

I'm enclosing a picture for those who don't want to run the snippet:

[image: screenshot from the snippet]

I tried using `flex-wrap` on the footer but it works only if I'm setting a width on the footer, which I'd prefer not to do.

```css
.container {
  background-color: grey;
  display: inline-block;
}

.narrow-child {
  background-color: green;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
}

.large-child {
  background-color: green;
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
}

.footer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  /*width: 100px;*/
}

.footer-sub-element1 {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 80px;
  height: 50px;
}

.footer-sub-element2 {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 90px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="narrow-child">
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="footer-sub-element1">
    </div>
    <div class="footer-sub-element2">
    I want this to wrap
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="large-child">
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="footer-sub-element1">
    </div>
    <div class="footer-sub-element2">
    I don't want this to wrap
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Will you know the width of the footer sub elements?

Comment: @ovokuro no i won't :(

Comment: The major problem is that the `container` is `inline-block`, which mean it will size with its content until it hit is parents width, in this case the body. To solve this you need to constrain its width in some way to achieve what you want

Answer (score 2):

The width of `.footer` cannot be dependent of a sibling without the use of JavaScript. A solution would be to define the width of the `.container` instead of the `.child`.

```css
.container {
  background-color: grey;
  display: inline-block;
}

.narrow {
  width: 100px;
}

.large {
  width: 300px;
}

.child {
  background-color: green;
  height: 200px;
}

.footer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  /*width: 100px;*/
}

.footer-sub-element1 {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 80px;
  height: 50px;
}

.footer-sub-element2 {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 90px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container narrow">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="footer-sub-element1">
    </div>
    <div class="footer-sub-element2">
    I want this to wrap
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container large">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="footer-sub-element1">
    </div>
    <div class="footer-sub-element2">
    I don't want this to wrap
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do that cleanly (I would have to add border, margin...)

Comment: If the exact solution doesn't work, the basic idea might still help: `.footer` cannot adjust its width to fit `.child` using just CSS. Use wrapper-`div`s or similar techniques to achieve the desired result.

Comment: Yes that's what I did. But ideally I would have liked it to work without setting any width (for example if the width of the green element depends on its own children or of some text inside it)